# Why is the box I marked with a red arrow empty and no class information given?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, instrument-procedures, jeppesen

Why is the box I marked with a red arrow empty and no class information given? On the NDB chart, both places are left blank. Am I supposed to consider the gap "FULL" by reference from the ILS minimums? In other charts of the same airport (VOR, ILS, NDB, etc.), this section is left blank. I also saw that these sections were left blank in different airport charts. Pictures from airport LTAF page 21-2 ILS Y or LOC Y Rwy 05 Jeppesen chart and airport LTAF page 26-1 NDB Z Rwy 05 Jeppesen chart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Full" means that ***everything*** is working, including TDZ (touchdown zone lights) & CL (centerline lights) along with the approach lights (ALS). To get the lowest mins for an ILS, all of that is required, and any inop component gives you "less than **Full**" and raises your mins.

In contrast, the other approaches you reference don't need CL or TDZ lighting in order for the lowest mins to apply, so "Full" wouldn't be accurate. Not having TDZ and or CL doesn't raise those mins.

In other words, you could think of the blank boxes as being like "Full or TDZ out and/or CL out"... any condition that isn't "ALS Out" gets the mins in that column.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, you have been helpful.